# Why did Deidara want to kill Orochimaru?

Tags: naruto

In the anime it was shown that Deidara was so fixated on killing Orochimaru by himself, he also recklessly attacked Sasuke for killing(!) Orochimaru...

> It was shown that Deidara joined Akatsuki only after Orochimaru left,
>   So what could be the reason for his desire to kill Orochimaru by himself?
>   Is it said anywhere in story?

Comment: I can't recall well, but deidara got mention about it during his fight against sasuke. One thing is for sure diedara hated the sharingan and Orchimaru is one of the reason he had to join Akatsuki after easily being defeated Itachi.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

More information about Deidara can be found on [this link](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Deidara):

> When Deidara's exploits caught the attention of the Akatsuki, Itachi
>   Uchiha, Kisame Hoshigaki, and Sasori were sent to recruit him. Deidara
>   refused at first but accepts a challenge from Itachi on the condition
>   that the Akatsuki let him be if he won. However, Deidara was easily
>   defeated by Itachi's Sharingan and begrudgingly joined the
>   organisation. -> Chapter 359.
>
> His ego crushed since then because he admitted to himself that the
>   Sharingan was a work of art, Deidara carried a murderous loathing for
>   Itachi and the Sharingan for the rest of his life. Acknowledging that
>   Itachi was a more powerful opponent, Deidara took steps during his
>   time with the Akatsuki to get revenge on Itachi, such as training his
>   left eye to counter genjutsu, and devising the means to create C4.

Now since Itachi easily defeated Orochimaru, Deidara wanted to defeat
him as well to show off and prove to Itachi that he is strong. You can
say, Itachi defeated Orochimaru, then he MUST defeat him as well.